# QEMU arm permanent storage

Tags: linux, arm, qemu

I use QEMU with an arm linux kernel. The changes such as new folders and files are gone when the guest is rebooted. I could not find a way to make them permanent. 
These are the files :

```
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root   197120 Ağu 14 17:45 disk.img
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 57424384 Ağu 14 13:28 rootfs.cpio
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62914560 Ağu 14 13:28 rootfs.ext2
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    11863 Ağu 14 13:28 vexpress-v2p-ca9.dtb
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29247264 Ağu 14 13:28 zImage
```

This is the running of QEMU:

```
C:\Program Files\qemu>qemu-system-arm -M vexpress-a9 -kernel zImage  -serial COM1  --nographic -hda disk.img
```

This is the result of df call at guest

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 34324         0     34324   0% /dev
tmpfs                    62460         0     62460   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    62460        24     62436   0% /tmp
tmpfs                    62460        24     62436   0% /run
```

qemu block info:

```
(qemu) info block
info block
none0 (#block133): D:/images/disk.img (raw)
    Removable device: not locked, tray closed
    Cache mode:       writeback

none2: [not inserted]
    Removable device: not locked, tray closed

floppy0: [not inserted]
    Removable device: not locked, tray closed

sd0: [not inserted]
    Removable device: not locked, tray closed
```

dev list:

## ls /dev

```
audio               tty13               tty52
console             tty14               tty53
cpu_dma_latency     tty15               tty54
dsp                 tty16               tty55
full                tty17               tty56
input               tty18               tty57
kmem                tty19               tty58
kmsg                tty2                tty59
log                 tty20               tty6
mem                 tty21               tty60
mixer               tty22               tty61
network_latency     tty23               tty62
network_throughput  tty24               tty63
null                tty25               tty7
psaux               tty26               tty8
ptmx                tty27               tty9
pts                 tty28               ttyAMA0
ptyp0               tty29               ttyAMA1
ptyp1               tty3                ttyAMA2
ptyp2               tty30               ttyAMA3
ptyp3               tty31               ttyp0
ptyp4               tty32               ttyp1
ptyp5               tty33               ttyp2
ptyp6               tty34               ttyp3
ptyp7               tty35               ttyp4
ptyp8               tty36               ttyp5
ptyp9               tty37               ttyp6
ptypa               tty38               ttyp7
ptypb               tty39               ttyp8
ptypc               tty4                ttyp9
ptypd               tty40               ttypa
ptype               tty41               ttypb
ptypf               tty42               ttypc
random              tty43               ttypd
rtc0                tty44               ttype
shm                 tty45               ttypf
snd                 tty46               urandom
tty                 tty47               usbmon0
tty0                tty48               vcs
tty1                tty49               vcs1
tty10               tty5                vcsa
tty11               tty50               vcsa1
tty12               tty51               zero
```

lsblk not exists.

How can i make a permanent storage?

Comment: Please add output of "ls /dev/" and "lsblk" commands executed on your guest. This need to understand which block devices are available

Comment: I have added "ls /dev/", but i'm afraid "lsblk" does not exist. 
I  have also added the "info block" from the qemu command line interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long hours of research I have found that: 
"*Note that we must -sd instead of -sda because vexpress kernel doesn't support PCI SCSI hard disks*" from [buildroot vexpress-a9 usage](https://gist.github.com/Liryna/10710751)